# Installation of PR2 simulation

Tags: gazebo, simulation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i followed the instruction from:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/StartingPR2Simulation
after making the full installation of ros fuerte
and i got this error:

```
lab116@ubuntu:~$ rosmake pr2_gazebo [rosmake ] rosmake starting...         
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are:
['pr2_gazebo']                        
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory
/home/lab116/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120809-123551
[ rosmake ] Expanded args
['pr2_gazebo'] to: []                 
[ rosmake ] **WARNING: The following
args could not be parsed as stacks or**
packages: ['pr2_gazebo'] [ rosmake ]
**ERROR: **No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.****
```

i tried to install the pr2_gazebo:

```
lab116@ubuntu:~$ rosdep  install pr2_gazebo

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required
resources to answer your query Missing
resource pr2_gazebo ROS path
[0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros ROS path
[1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share ROS path
[2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
```

How do i install this pkg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40959/installation-of-pr2-simulation/) by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't do a manual installation. It seems like you already installed ros from debian packages, so just install the debian package for the pr2 simulation:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-simulator
```

There's no rosmake nor rosdep installed required. Just start the simulation with:

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4